# Behat + mink + Selenium2 + chromeDriver: Do not launch chrome browser

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, behat

I am using ubuntu 14.4.

When I run the test its works fine with firefox, where it launches the FF browser.

But when I try the same with Chrome the test runs but it do not launch the browser.

composer.json

```
{
    "require": {
    "behat/behat": "2.4.*@stable",
    "behat/mink": "1.5.*@stable",
    "behat/mink-goutte-driver": "*",
    "behat/mink-extension": "*",
    "behat/mink-selenium2-driver": "*"
    }
}
```

behat.yml

```
default:
 paths:
  features: features
  bootstrap: %behat.paths.features%/bootstrap
 extensions:
  Behat\MinkExtension\Extension:
    base_url:  'path-to-my-site'
    default_session: selenium2
    browser_name: 'chrome'
    goutte: ~
    selenium2:
        wd_host: "http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub"
```

Command to start Selenium Server

```
java -jar /path-to/selenium-server-standalone-2.47.1.jar -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="/usr/local/share/chromedriver"
```

This is output of my above command:

```
11:27:46.064 INFO - Launching a standalone Selenium Server
Setting system property webdriver.chrome.driver to /usr/local/share/chromedriver
11:27:46.101 INFO - Java: Oracle Corporation 24.72-b04
11:27:46.101 INFO - OS: Linux 3.13.0-32-generic amd64
11:27:46.113 INFO - v2.47.1, with Core v2.47.1. Built from revision 411b314
11:27:46.181 INFO - Driver provider org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver registration is skipped:
registration capabilities Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, ensureCleanSession=true, browserName=internet explorer, version=}] does not match the current platform LINUX
11:27:46.182 INFO - Driver provider org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver registration is skipped:
registration capabilities Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, browserName=MicrosoftEdge, version=}] does not match the current platform LINUX
11:27:46.182 INFO - Driver class not found: com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver
11:27:46.182 INFO - Driver provider com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver is not registered
11:27:46.249 INFO - RemoteWebDriver instances should connect to: http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub
11:27:46.249 INFO - Selenium Server is up and running
```

Behat test command:

```
vendor/bin/behat
```

Output of behat test

```
Feature: Home page
    I am on a home page

  Scenario: Visit homepage                       # features/test.feature:4
    Given I go to "home.html"                    # FeatureContext::visit()
    Then I should see "We can change the world!" # FeatureContext::assertPageContainsText()
    Then I follow "Register"                     # FeatureContext::clickLink()

1 scenario (1 passed)
3 steps (3 passed)
```

Problem is the Test Works but the chrome browser is not launched. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [Running selenium server standalone and chromedriver](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/js7k/running-selenium-server-standalone-and-cromedriver) and [Running behat2 tests with different browsers](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/6djs/running-behat2-tests-with-different-browsers)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add `@javascript` tag before scenario, because by default behat is using `goutte` session which is not using selenium webdriver. More about [Goutte driver](http://mink.behat.org/en/latest/drivers/goutte.html)

```
@javascript
Scenario: Visit homepage
```

Or in `behat.yml` set the default session to `selenium2`

```
extensions:
    Behat\MinkExtension\Extension:
      default_session: selenium2
```

But after that behat will launch `firefox` browser, for launching especially `chrome` - you should add `browser_name: chrome` option

```
extensions:
    Behat\MinkExtension\Extension:
      browser_name: chrome
```

And also you should specify `wd_host` params for the `selenium2` config param

```
extensions:
    Behat\MinkExtension\Extension:
      selenium2:
            wd_host: "http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub"
```

Comment: I tried both your above solutions. Now when I run behat test its says: Could not open connection

Comment: add the following to your `behat.yml` config `selenium2:
                wd_host: "http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub"`

Comment: config... means where and how do I write?

Comment: I mean - in `behat.yml` you have the next lines `selenium2: browser: chrome` you need to replace them with `selenium2:
            wd_host: "http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub"` and dont forget to add `browser_name: chrome` param under `Behat\MinkExtension\Extension`

Comment: I had updated my behat.yml file. please check. still it says: could not open connection

Comment: nope. didnt worked.  `Scenario: Visit homepage                       # features/test.feature:4
    Given I go to "home.html"                    # FeatureContext::visit()
      Could not open connection
`

Comment: Now I get this error - `Scenario: Visit homepage                       # features/test.feature:4
    Given I go to "home.html"                    # FeatureContext::visit()
    Then I should see "We can change the world!" # FeatureContext::assertPageContainsText()
      Element not found with xpath, //html`

Comment: But is browser launching? If yes, then check the `base_url ` param, is it correct or not. but this error comes from page asserion which means that connection phase is done. So after `Given I go to "home.html"` you could write `Then print last response` step and check the url and response of the page.

Comment: yes browser launches... it just flashes and is vanished... cant even see which browser was launched...chrome of FF...

Comment: as i mentioned above - try to add `Then print last response` step after `Given I go to "home.html"` and it will gives you the url which selenium try to open and also response from that page.

Comment: well the browser launches when I write this : `wd_host: "http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub"` (and behaves as I mentioned in my above comment - it flashes) but not otherwise when I add this `http://0.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub`

Comment: I tried as you said- added the line `Then print last response step` after `Given I go to "home.html"` AND OUTPUT is  `Scenario: Visit homepage                 # features/test.feature:4
    Given I go to "/"                            # FeatureContext::visit()

|  
|  
|  

    Then print last response                     # FeatureContext::printLastResponse()
    Then I should see "We can change the world!" # FeatureContext::assertPageContainsText()
      Element not found with xpath, //html
    Then I follow "Register" ` 3 blank spaces with | on each line before `Then print last response`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91058/discussion-between-igor-lantushenko-and-prits).

Comment: Thanks a million!!! It worked. Chrome Browser version was a probelm. Thanks a lot for all your help and time :)